# How to save video from HTTP to photo library in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios6

I want to download some video from HTTP into user's ios device. How could we use AVAssetsLibrary to do that? I tried but got the following error:

Video /wikipedia/commons/4/4d/F1_vid2.theora.ogv cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2 "This movie could not be played." UserInfo=xxxxxxxx {NSLocalizedDescription=This movie could not be played.}

Thanks a bunch!

My code is:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
        if ([lib videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:videoURL]) {
          [lib writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoURL
              completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                  if (!error) {
                    result = KIFTestStepResultSuccess;
                    NSLog(@"yuanzi: Completed writing videos.");
                  }
                  saved = YES;
          }];
        }
```